# Multiple instances of a Joomla 1.5 Component

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, forums

I have a site I am working on and I want to have forums for different categories of users. Is it possible to have multiple instances of a Joomla forum component or do I have to install multiple forums to suit each of these user categories.

Alternatively, is there any Joomla forum that displays different content and topic based on user categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joomla 1.5 this is much more complex than Joomla 2.5. Joomla 2.5 allows categories of users to be set natively. Joomla 1.5 is also not supported by Joomla anymore and has known security flaws.

However you can install the component [artof user](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/14383) and the [kunena](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum/7256) forum component. These should integrate together to give the desired result!

Comment: What do you mean by: "In Joomla 1.5 this is much more complex than Joomla 1.5" ?

Comment: sorry typo :) second instance should have read Joomla 2.5 fixed